# How to access an object within object within object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, nested

```
var shape =   {
         circle: {
             colors: {
                blue: "#0066FF",
                red: "#FF3300"
                     }
                  },

       radius: 20
};
```

SO I was trying to acces the object "blue" and could not do it.
How do I access the object "blue"?

Comment: `shape.circle.colors.blue`. For example: `console.log(shape.circle.colors.blue);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways to access nested objects in javaScript :

```
// use this way for only some special cases like 
// when using reserved keywords or 
// using spaces or special characters or 
// if your property starts with number.

alert(shape.circle.colors["blue"]);
```

**OR**

```
alert(shape.circle.colors.red);
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/YyEd9/)

Answer (score 0):

As [bloodyKnuckles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2743458/bloodyknuckles) said, use `shape.circle.colors.blue`. When you have nested objects, you need to use dot notation multiple times in one expression.

```
//shape. [...]
var shape =   {
    //[...] circle. [...]
    circle: {
        //[...] colors. [...]
        colors: {
            //[...] blue
            blue: "#0066FF",
            red: "#FF3300"
        }
    },
    radius: 20
};

console.log(shape.circle.colors.blue);
```